# querying a database from F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

Is this possible? I've tried but I am getting errors.  I have a solution with a F# project that I have applied the **Send Project Output to F# Interactive** option.  For added info, this project is not the startup project. After opening the targeted namespaces, when I enter the function that is supposed to query the database I get a long list of errors, but appears to start with this line:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'InterviewTools.Support' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   '<-StartupCode$Engine->.$InterviewTools' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   '<-StartupCode$Engine->.$DbTools' threw an exception. --->
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0\Web.config'.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Does the linked file exist?

Comment: No, it does not. What's going on here? Why is it looking for a web.config file there?

Comment: What are you using to talk to your db? A type provider?

Comment: Yes. SqlDataConnection.

Comment: It is possible to query interactively.  See this http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/low-risk-ways-to-use-fsharp-at-work-4/#sql-linqpad. I'm not sure what is causing your error though.

Comment: Grundoon, thanks for that.  Looks like that's the route I'll have to take in the meantime.